# Why is my thor copy_file command not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, thor

I am trying to setup a rails app template and have this code in my sample.rb template file:

```
run "bundle install"

copy_file "/Users/amiterandole/Desktop/current/rails/templates/guard/Guardfile", "."
```

The bundle install runs just fine but the copy command fails with this error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:47:in `binread': Is a directory - /Users/amiterandole/Desktop/current/rails/templates/myapp (Errno::EISDIR)
```

I can't understand this error and how to fix it. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: please show your thor configs

Comment: @Lichtamberg I don't have these actually. What exactly are these? Can you point me to the documentation? I am using a standalone ruby file

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying a destination file path including the filename.

```
copy_file "/Users/amiterandole/Desktop/current/rails/templates/guard/Guardfile", "my_destination_path/Guardfile"
```